# SMTP client program gives run-time error

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I can compile my code but not execute. What could be the reason and how should i sort it
I get the following run-time errors.

```
C:\>java SMTPClient
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to S
MTP host: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port: 465;
nested exception is..................etc</b></code>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please provide the `root cause` or `Stack trace` of the Exception.
It may be because you haven't configured `Authenticator`

Comment: I am not able to post entire error since everytime i get OOPS your code cannot be pasted since it has code i tried adding code tags but it didn't help

Answer (score 2):

probably SMTPClient uses a SMTP protocol, but yahoo uses more secure one like ASMTP. can you post your SMTPClient class here?

Answer (score 2):

The JavaMail FAQ has [instructions for connecting to Yahoo mail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#yahoomail), as well as [debugging tips for when it doesn't work](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that it cannot connect to the Yahoo Mail Server.  I'm unsure of Yahoo's mail port so ensure that the port is correct. Can you post more details? I.e. the nested exception....

Comment: C:\>java SMTPClient
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to
MTP host: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorEx
eption: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBu
lderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Looks like you need an SSL certificate